# Least number of squares of size N that a set of R rectangles can occupy

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Given a set $R$ of rectangles of different positive integer sizes, and any number of squares of the same size $N\in\mathbb{N}$, what's the least number of squares $C$ that all the rectangles together can occupy if you can put them in any configuration?

Also, what is the ratio of the total area of the squares vs the total area of all the rectangles in $R$?

I know of works talking about optimal rectangular packing: the smallest bounding box that can accommodate all the rectangles in R. The answer to that can be related if $N=1$, then $C$ becomes $\lceil m \rceil\lceil n \rceil$. In that case, the resulting squares have to tile a larger rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Presumably $N$ is not necessarily a positive integer? In which case, $s$ might be a better symbol for the square side length.